# JBoss Fuse Tooling - Camel "dozer" transaformation GUI wizard

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, fusetools

I would like to use the Dozer Mapping tool for Camel and it works well with Spring XML.

I prefer to use Java DSL and I would like to somehow get the wizard to popup but I don't have a Components toolbox to drag and drop it.

Any suggestions?

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Transformation Editor in Fuse Tooling is tied with Graphical Camel Editor (Spring or Blueprint DSL). Unfortunately, there is no way how to enable it on Java DSL.

You can raise a new issue (enhancement) here https://issues.jboss.org/projects/FUSETOOLS to let the developers know about it ;-)

Comment: Thomas, will it work in a XML and Java DSL environment? I can create XML routes for the transoforms and then route back to Java DSL. Will that work?

Comment: Yes, that should be a feasible solution (separate transformation logic into another project based on Spring/Blueprint XML DSL and use `direct-vm` component to communicate with your Java DSL project)